# Apache Geode Integration with Postgresql DBMS

Tags: postgresql, geode

I am looking to integrate Apache Geode with Postgresql DBMS but not able to find steps to configure Geode to connect and retrieve data from Postgresql. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have a look at [Keeping the Cache in Sync with Outside Data Sources](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html), it basically explains how you can keep the distributed cache in sync with an external data source by the usage of Geode plug-ins for your regions. There's also an example regarding how you can configure your database connection using JNDI (`PostgreSQL` included).

Cheers.

Comment: Hey Juan,
Thanks for suggestions, I did go through the documentation and tried the approach but that doesn't work. I am looking for a detailed example of anyone has practically integrated this approach.
Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can try [this one](https://github.com/apache/geode-examples/tree/develop/jdbc)?. It's for `MySQL`, not `PostgreSQL`, but the steps are basically the same, you probably just need to replace the driver.